# Creating Category Again while uploading products with CSV file

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have created category and subcategory and try to upload products to those category and subcategory with CSV file but the problem is again it is creating category and subcategory.

Comment: please check with csv file, something wrong with category path.

Comment: Default Category/Endodontics,Default Category/Endodontics/Endo Files,Default Category/Endodontics/Endo Files/H Files i have given like this